# Node.js mongodb trouble with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

So I'm trying to create a sign up route that checks to see if the user exists first and i have the database call in a separate function that needs to return *`true`* or *`false`* when it's done. The problem is i'm not very familiar with callbacks and the whole asynchronous thing everything that i have searched for does not seem to work keeps giving me.

*`TypeError: callback is not a function`*

This is my code any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
function pullUserFromDatabase(username, callback) {



console.log(username); //for debug
    mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
                console.log("didn't get far" + err) //for debug

            }

        var collection = db.collection(username);

        collection.findOne({username}, function(err, item) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("nope it broke" + err) //for debug

            } else {
                console.log("it worked" + JSON.stringify(item)) //for debug
                callback(true);
            }
        });




});

}

app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var username = req.headers["username"],
        password = req.headers["password"],
        randomSalt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
        passwordHashOutput = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password + randomSalt).digest("hex");

        if(!username || !password) {
            res.send("Username or password not provided.")
        } else if(pullUserFromDatabase(username)) {
            res.send("User exist.")
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback as follows:

```
function pullUserFromDatabase(data, callback) { 
    console.log(data.username); //for debug
    mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("didn't get far" + err) //for debug
        }

        var collection = db.collection(data.collection);
        collection.find({"username": data.username}).count(function (err, count) {
            callback(err, !! count);
        });
    });
};




app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var username = req.headers["username"],
        password = req.headers["password"],
        randomSalt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
        passwordHashOutput = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password + randomSalt).digest("hex");

        if(!username || !password) {
            res.send("Username or password not provided.")
        } 

        var data = {
            username: username,
            collection: "collectionName"            
        }

        if(!username || !password) {
            res.send("Username or password not provided.")
        }

        pullUserFromDatabase(data, function(err, exists) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(400, "Error - " + err);
            }
            else if(exists) {
                res.send(200, "User exists.");
            }
            res.send(200, "User does not exist.");
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You really cleared it up for me but my question is how would one wrap that whole thing into the original function so that if you do a else if that you only care whether the function be called returns true or false or is that not good practice? or is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You need to do the if-else logic inside the function callback because the variable where you would store the information about the user existing will be from the result of the function to be called. That's the general pattern; do the logic in the function callback.

Comment: I see. So let's say i want to do something more advanced. Like a var array of functions like how you setup var data but with functions so data.pullPosts would in essence be setup the same way that you did pullUserFromDatabase(data, function(err, exists). Documentation(mongos is horrible), google and stackover flow can only take you so far but when you want to make really complicated things there lacking.

Comment: also I'm curios as to what the not not count is for i know that count returns 1 if it exists or 0 if not right? so whats the !! for?

Comment: Answering your last question as the first one is a bit broad and warrants you to open a new question; According to the docs the second argument of the callback to the cursor.count() method will contain the number of results or null if an error occurred. For this example, as a simple test `var count = 2; console.log(!! count); // prints true` whilst  `var count = 0; console.log(!! count); // prints false`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `callback` is undefined is because you didn't pass a 2nd argument to `pullUserFromDatabase(username)`  Provide a 2nd argument, eg. `pullUserFromDatabase(username, function(result) {/* do something here with the result variable */})`

If you're not very familiar with aync & callbacks, you might find it more intuitive to use *promises*, but that comes with its own learning curve.

In the context of the original code, this looks like:

```
    ...
    if(!username || !password) {
        res.send("Username or password not provided.");
        return;
    } 

    pullUserFromDatabase(username, function(result) {
        if(result) {
           res.send("User exist.");
        } else { 
           // TODO: Handle this case.  If res.send() is never called, the HTTP request won't complete
        }
    });
    ...
```

Also, you need to ensure your callback is always invoked.  Add callback(false):

```
   console.log("nope it broke" + err); //for debug
   callback(false);
```

Do a similar step after `"didn't get far"` and then `return` so the callback doesn't get invoked multiple times.

Comment: Still get TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: I think your missing what I'm trying to do the else if can only be true or false and the pullUserFromDatabase() I'm trying to get the nested function  collection.findOne to return a value to it's main parent function pullUserFromDatabase()